# Group dataframe by rows and compare values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes.
`old_results` =

```
date      | location | value | trial_number
----------+----------+-------+-------------
1-1-2001  | USA      | 3     | 10 
1-2-2001  | USA      | 4     | 20 
1-1-2001  | China    | 1     | 30
1-2-2001  | China    | 2     | 40
```

`new_results` =

```
date      | location | value |trial_number
----------+----------+-------+-------------
1-1-2001  | China    | 10    | 1
1-2-2001  | China    | 100   | 2
1-1-2001  | USA      | 1000  | 3
1-2-2001  | USA      | 10000 | 4
1-1-2001  | USA      | 5     | 5
1-2-2001  | USA      | 50    | 6
```

- Note: there is no guarantee of order in this dataframe, and that there are repeated values in the dataframe.

I want to add a column to the `new_results` dataframe called `diff`, which compares the old and new values for a given date/location combo. So the final result should look like:

```
date      | location | value | diff                | trial_number
----------+----------+-------+---------------------+-------------
1-1-2001  | China    | 10    | 9     # 10 - 1      | 1
1-2-2001  | China    | 100   | 98    # 100 - 2     | 2
1-1-2001  | USA      | 1000  | 997   # 1000 - 3    | 3
1-2-2001  | USA      | 10000 | 9996  # 1000 - 4    | 4
1-1-2001  | USA      | 1000  | 2   # 5 - 3         | 5
1-2-2001  | USA      | 10000 | 46  # 50 - 4        | 6
```

I know how to use `groupby` to create dataframe groups, but I do not know how to compare groupbys, and use the results to modify the initial dataframe.

Comment: `new_result['diff'] = new_result['value'] - old_results['value']`

Comment: There is no guarantee of order, would this still work? (updating question to reflect this)